# every time only "else case alert dialog" is invoking?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

please help me with this code:
every time only the else case is executing not the if case i have a html file in asset/www folder and this is listview
Here i am providing the ListviewActivity i will have max of 20 in that list and each list will have an webview

//this is the data in the list view
     private String arr[]={"sunny","cool","hot","rainy"};
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
            /*Intent myIntent = new Intent(SpellsActivity.this, Details.class);

            myIntent.putExtra("key",(String) list.getItemAtPosition(position));
            startActivity(myIntent);*/
            String str =(String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Context mContext= SpellsActivity.this;
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);



          //this is where i need you to see only else case is invoking not the if    

            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(arr[0])){
            alert.setTitle("Sunny");
            WebView wv=new WebView(mContext);
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/sunny.html");
            }
             else{
                 alert.setTitle("Cool");
                 WebView wv=new WebView(mContext);
                 wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/cool.html");*/
             }


            alert.setView(wv);
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Back",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BACK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
              });

            alert.show();
        }

    });

}

}
```

For testing whether it is working or not i have just used the two options sunny or else

Comment: sorry friends got the answer but unable to post it because of less reputation will post it after 6hrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry friends that its not the like if is not invoked but the web-view in the if clause is not executed because of the objects

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
             WebView wv=new WebView(mContext);
             if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(arr[0])){
             alert.setTitle("if");
              wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/sunny.html");
            }
             else{
                 alert.setTitle("else");

                 wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/cool.html");
             }
```

now it is perfect.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a bit of more code regarding the data you are using to set your list view. Probably there could be difference in the data that's leading to execute the else part of condition. ..